# Is IronRuby ScriptSource.Execute thread safe?

Tags: .net, performance, multithreading, ironruby, expression-evaluation

We are implemented expression evaluator via hosting IronRuby engine. Simplified version of evaluator you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660887/ironruby-performance-issue-while-using-variables).

Now we are trying to get more performance from IronRuby via executing expressions in many threads (and we got it). One question bothers us - is Execute method thread safe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ScriptRuntime`, `ScriptEngine`, and `ScriptScope` are all thread safe, designed to be used between threads. Specifically, `ScriptScope` uses a thread-safe data-store, so `ScriptScope` can be shared between threads.

If you provide your own scope for scripts to execute against, you will need to ensure that scope's data store is thread-safe. Also, when mutating data in a `ScriptScope`, thread-safety is ensured by locking, so be aware that many different threads mutating a shared `ScriptScope` will degrade performance. Reading data from a ScriptScope does not lock.

Comment: Why were you using threads for perf, and how have you seen it degrade?

Comment: I just updated my answer, after finding out that the hosting API is in-fact thread-safe. This should make your performance boosts come back =)